# Can Android .apk files be installed in a regular Linux PC?

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, dalvik

Is it possible to install `.apk` files in linux PC? Not in emulator

I ask that questions because Android OS have linux kernel as a base. If you want to see Android Architecture [Click Here](http://www.android-app-market.com/android-architecture.html).

Comment: Not on a regular linux pc but http://www.android-x86.org/ comes close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Android phones do have the linux kernel, but that is the very, very bottom core. Android has many, many other utilities that open and use the .apk file.

This is a useful picture of the Android "build". This was make by google.
Link: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/af/Android-System-Architecture.svg

This gives a little more detail of what your asking and a little more.

Comment: if its there is any possibility to install dalvik virtual machine then i can able to run apk files in linux enviroment

Answer (score 1):

> The elements that are contained inside the apk file are specifically
> designed and designated to be used in Android mobile phones and not a
> desktop PC running Linux. Though Android uses the Linux kernel, you
> definitely cannot run the apk file on a Linux machine, as you would an
> rpm or a deb file.
>
> Install Android OS on your PC, if you really want to run them from a computer.

Comment: It's obviously correct but as you use a citation style, I guess there is a source. Can you link to it ?

Answer (score 0):

No. .apk files are just a collection of source and resource files which are not executable just by themselves, no matter on which platform. The Android OS puts them together so that you can run them eventually. That being said, of course there is a way to run apk's on Linux. It's called an AVD (Android Virtual Device). That's an emulator, and available with the SDK.

Comment: That's right but OP precised "Not in emulator".

Comment: Whoops. Anyway, it's still true.